# EXIF / rotate image

Tags: php, exif, verot-upload-class

I've been using a great class to manipulate images for a number of years.

[class.upload.php](https://github.com/verot/class.upload.php)

Currently I need to be able to determine if the image is side wards and rotate it, to vertical position. I understand that I can use

```
$handle->image_auto_rotate  = true;
```

But for some reason I'm not having much luck. The image I was testing with is JPEG.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not having much luck - could you be a little more specific?

Comment: the documentation: echo $handle->log; so you get some info on what/why doesn't work as expected (have you tried?)

Comment: By "not have luck" I meant I tried but the image is not being rotated. I did look at the log and see that my image's orientation is: Rotate 90 CW, yet, after it is uploaded is is still sideways.

Comment: (class.upload.php src)  /**
     * Rotates the image by increments of 45 degrees
     *
     * Value is either 90, 180 or 270
     *
     * Default value is null (no rotation)
     *
     * access public
     * var string;
     */
    var $image_rotate;

Comment: have you tried setting $image_rotate, see if that has an impact?

Comment: var $image_auto_rotate; is default set to true (i.e. automatically rotates the image according to EXIF data (JPEG only)

Comment: I tried this but did not get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Use: `$handle->image_rotate = '90';`

Comment: I need to determine if an image is side-ward before applying rotation.